# Unable to check and uncheck checkbox in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks

When i choose check in checkbox the value should be inserted in hobby array and when i unchecked the value should be removed from array
value is inserting and removing  from array but i am not able to check and unchecked the checkbox visually. but in state it's working.

```
 const ContactForm = () => {
 const [state,setContact] = useState({
        userId:"",
        firstName:"",
        lastName:"",
        jobTitleName:"",
        employeeCode:"",
        emailAddress:"",
        phoneNumber:"",
        country:"",
        status:"active",
        hobbies:[]
 })   
 const onChange = (event)=>{   
    setContact({...state,[event.target.name]: event.target.value}); 
  }
  e.preventDefault();
 }
return (
   <div className="form-group mb-2">
    <label className="mb-0 font-weight-bold">Hobbies</label>
    <div className="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Basketball"   onChange={(e)=>{
       if(e.target.checked)

       {
        state.hobbies.push(e.target.value)
        console.log(state.hobbies)
    }else { 
        var index = state.hobbies.indexOf(e.target.value);
        if (index > -1) {
          state.hobbies.splice(index, 1);
          console.log(state.hobbies)
        }
      }
     }
    }
  />

  <label className="form-check-label">
   Basketball
  </label>
</div>
<div className="form-check">
<input type="checkbox" value="Vollyball"   onChange={(e)=>{
       if(e.target.checked)
       {
        state.hobbies.push(e.target.value)
        console.log(state.hobbies)
    }else { 
        var index = state.hobbies.indexOf(e.target.value);
        if (index > -1) {
            state.hobbies.splice(index, 1);
            console.log(state.hobbies)
        }
       }
      }
     }
   />
<label className="form-check-label">
      Vollyball
      </label>
    </div>
       </div>
    )
```

Comment: Please provide only the code with which you are having trouble, what you have tried and what the problem is clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mutating state. Your updating state value witout useState's method `setContact`.

Please find working code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-diffie-giqgr

When you mutate state or change state value without useState method or setState it won't re-render component even though your state value is changed. You `onChange` should be like this.

```
if (e.target.checked) {
              const newState = {
                ...state,
                hobbies: [...state.hobbies, e.target.value]
              };
              setContact(newState);
              console.log("** checked", newState);

              // state.hobbies.push(e.target.value);
              // console.log(state.hobbies);
            } else {
              const newState = {
                ...state,
                hobbies: state.hobbies.filter(prev => prev !== e.target.value)
              };
              console.log("** unchecked", newState);

              setContact(newState);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

For your reference sample application

how to use multiple checkbox and adding multiple values.

```
const checkboxes = [
  'Cricket', 'Footbal', 'Tennis'
];
class App extends Component {
    state = {
      checkedItems: new Map(),
    }
   handleChange=(e)=> {
    const item = e.target.name;
    const isChecked = e.target.checked;
    this.setState(prevState => ({ checkedItems: prevState.checkedItems.set(item, isChecked) }));
   }

  render() {   
    console.log(this.state.checkedItems) 
    return (
      <>
        {
          checkboxes.map(item => (
            <label key={item}>
              {item}
             <input type="checkbox" 
             checked={this.state.checkedItems.get(item)} 
             onChange={this.handleChange} 
             name={item}/>
            </label>
          ))
        }
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer using es6 map and set. but some of the reactjs devs just wants to use functional components. It's better if you translate it to fc.